# Ubuntu. Куча ошибок "undefined reference to" в make

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

Пытаюсь установить программу https://github.com/arsf/lag

Вот результат ./configure

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GTKmm... yes
checking for GTKGLextmm... yes
checking for GThread... yes
checking for laslib... yes
checking for lidarquadtree... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

Вроде бы все окей, как я понимаю.

А вот make выдает огромное количество ошибок "undefined reference to" (тут привожу лишь малую их часть):

```
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x35b): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x370): undefined reference to `Glib::Cond::signal()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::isDrawing()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x3b1): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::lock()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x3bd): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::run()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::stop()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::~DrawWorker()':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to `Glib::Dispatcher::~Dispatcher()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `DrawWorker::draw(PointBucket**, int)':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text+0x382): undefined reference to `Glib::Mutex::unlock()'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN10DrawWorkerC2EP10LagDisplay':
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x10): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x17): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::~ustring()'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x40): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x69): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x92): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0xbb): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0xe4): undefined reference to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)'
src/lag-DrawWorker.o:DrawWorker.cpp:(.text.startup+0x10d): more undefined references to `Glib::ustring::ustring(char const*)' follow
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::SelectionBox(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `Point::Point()'
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xa3): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::SelectionBox(Point, Point, Point, Point)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x116): undefined reference to `Point::Point()'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::move(double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::translate(double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x229): undefined reference to `Point::translate(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::SelectionBox(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::movePoint(int, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x24c): undefined reference to `Point::move(double, double, double)'
src/lag-SelectionBox.o: In function `SelectionBox::translatePoint(int, double, double, double)':
SelectionBox.cpp:(.text+0x25c): undefined reference to `Point::translate(double, double, double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:525: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «lag»
make[1]: *** [lag] Ошибка 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/home/meeeeee/lag-master»
Makefile:375: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «all»
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
```

Возникает вопрос: почему сборка не проходит? Как можно пофиксить все эти ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Текущий пользователь имеет привилегии администратора?
2. Если нет, то выполняется ли `make` с `sudo`
3. Установлен ли в системе `lidarquadtree` и библиотеки перечисленные в списке README на GitHub?

Comment: Пробовал собирать и с sudo, но толку от этого нет. lidarquadtree установлен и ./configure это подтверждает (checking for lidarquadtree... yes)

Comment: В readme есть раздел о Ubuntu. If this happens, you have two options: 1) Install the `binutils-gold` package before compiling 2) After `./configure` and before running `make`, apply the provided patch: `patch Makefile < ubuntu-Makefile.patch`

Comment: binutils-gold - установлен, а вот патчинг не проходит (уже ни единожды пытался): patching file Makefile
Hunk #1 FAILED at 405.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Makefile.rej
Плюс писал разработчикам самой программы с просьбой уточнить этапы установки на Ubuntu и они про данный патч даже ничего не упомянули, поэтому особого значения этому я не придал.

Comment: Что в файле Makefile.rej? Пытались удалить и сгенерировать новые Makefile и config.h?

Comment: *** /dev/null
--- /dev/null
***************
*** 405
-  $(lag_LINK) $(lag_OBJECTS) $(lag_LDADD) $(LIBS)
--- 405,407 -----
+  $(CXXLD) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(lag_LDFLAGS) \
+  $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(lag_OBJECTS) $(lag_LDADD) $(LIBS) \
+  $(lag_LDADD) $(lag_LDFLAGS)

Comment: Пробовал и удалять, и делать make clean после нового ./configure. Толку нет. При make clean пару минут идет сборка, а потом вываливается все та же тонна строк про undefined reference to.

Comment: Проблему решил! Пришлось руками добавлять то, что должен делать патч. После этого make и make install прошли без проблем. Спасибо большое за помощь!!!

Comment: Опишите, что добавляли. На этот же вопрос ещё кто-то наткнётся. Рад был помочь, хоть моя помощь и была бесполезна :)